# Why $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c-iT}^{c+iT} \frac{1}{s} ds = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{T} \frac{2c}{c^2+t^2}dt $?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I am trying to understand the equation
$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{c-iT}^{c+iT} \frac{1}{s} ds = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{T} \frac{2c}{c^2+t^2}dt $$ where it is given that $s=c+it$.
My work is as follows: I substitude $s=c+it, ds= idt$. Then $$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int \frac{1}{s} ds = \frac{1}{\pi} \int \frac{1}{c+it}dt = \frac{1}{\pi} \int \frac{c-it}{c^2+t^2}dt $$ and I also sense that $\int \frac{-it}{c^2+t^2}dt$ disappears by symmetry. I did not write the start and end points of the integral after substitution, because that is exactly what confuses me. I appreciate any help!

Comment: you need to be a bit less hand-wavy with the substitution and not confuse definite/path integrals with indefinite integrals. Start from the definition of a path integral and find a parametrization of the line segment connecting the two end points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. All you need is to put the limits of integration. At $s=c-iT$ you get the lower limit for $t$ as $-T$, and at $s=c+iT$, the upper limit will become $T$. Then $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT}\frac 1s ds=\frac1\pi\int_{-T}^T\frac{c-it}{c^2+t^2}dt=\frac1\pi\int_{-T}^T\frac{c}{c^2+t^2}dt-i\frac1\pi\int_{-T}^T\frac{t}{c^2+t^2}dt$$
The first integrand is even, the second is odd. Use $$\int_{-L}^L f_{odd}(x) dx=0\\\int_{-L}^L f_{even}(x) dx=2\int_0^L f_{even}(x) dx$$
This will get your desired result.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand the way I need to think about the end points. But it seems to me, for this particular example, we cannot pick the real part randomly, right? For instance could we substitude $s=-c+it$ or can we say the real part has to be $c$?

Comment: You will get a different (complex) integral. You want the real part to be $c$, to account for the limits in the original integral